# How to send the value to textbox programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have one textbox and to that textbox i have to send value from virtual keyboard i desigend.
I am send like

```
txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text.Insert(txtNumber.CaretIndex, ((Button)sender).Content.ToString());
txtNumber.CaretIndex += txtNumber.Text.Length;
txtNumber.focus();
```

The problem is when user forcefully place the cursor in between the text after typing some character, then pressing the key means first time the value is inserting correctly and after that cursor needs to be there.

This logic above make it to stay the cursor position in the end.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code, i have checked it:

```
        int CurrentIndex;
        private void textNumber_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentIndex = textNumber.SelectionStart;
        }

        private void Key_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textNumber.Text = textNumber.Text.Insert(CurrentIndex, "_");
        }
```

Comment: yeah its possible.But say "shan" user typed and after that placing cursor in the position of h and typed again means it should enter in that position only.
But simple txtNumber.Text += value will add in the end.
that is the problem.

Comment: I can't understand why are you trying to do this , because `textbox` has already this property to insert characters at the cursor position.

Comment: if we put textNumber.Text += value how it will insert in the particular position ?

Comment: textNumber_Click event belongs to textbox ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question, I would keep the string being modified in a buffer string variable and make your changes there depending on the virtual kb input. Once this is done, update the TextBox value by txtNumber.Text = bufferedString;

Answer (score 0):

try to do like this `txtNumber.Text +=// your code..`
and try to put `txtNumber.focus();` this line at the start.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple to ways you can do this.
When the user intents that he/she wants to use the virtual keyboard, 
by click of a checkbox or something, you can make the textbox readonly.
or you could set the `CaretIndex` in the `lost focus` event of the textbox.
else you can simply call the `AppendText("nextsetofchars")` method
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx

You can also set the `SelectionStart` to the length of the string in the lost focus event.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx